# How can I Target parent and child class I javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="inst4" class="block_navigation  block">
    <div class="content">
      <div> Content Start here !!!</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
        var blockNav = document.getElementsByClassName("block_navigation")[0].getElementsByClassName("content");
            blockNavIcon = document.createElement("img");
            blockNavIcon.setAttribute("src", blockIcon);
            blockNav.appendChild(blockNavIcon);  
        }
</script>
```

Here I am targeting content class, but it is not working, How can i do this any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few problems in your script, you are using the class `block_navigation` twice, also `blockNav` is a `NodeList`

You can easily use `.querySelector()`

```js
 var blockNav = document.querySelector(".block_navigation .content");
 blockNavIcon = document.createElement("img");
 blockNavIcon.setAttribute("src", '//placehold.it/64');
 blockNav.appendChild(blockNavIcon);
```

```html
<div id="inst4" class="block_navigation  block">
  <div class="content">
    <div>Content Start here !!!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you querySelector is javascript part or yui

Comment: @user3282537 javascript DOM - [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Answer (score 1):

You can use use `.getElementsByClassName("content")[0]`

Hope this wil be helpful

```
var blockIcon = "http://weknowyourdreams.com/images/forest/forest-04.jpg";
     var blockNav = document.getElementsByClassName("block_navigation")[0]
    .getElementsByClassName("content")[0]; // Will select the child element
    blockNavIcon = document.createElement("img");
                blockNavIcon.setAttribute("src", blockIcon);
                blockNav.appendChild(blockNavIcon)
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/1m1yg9df/1/)